# How and why do we write an ODE in a trigonometric form?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, roots

The solution of an ODE is found to be

$Y(x)=c_1e^{\lambda_1x}+c_2e^{-\lambda_1x}+c_3e^{i\lambda_2x}+c_4e^{-i\lambda_2x}$

The trigonometric form is written as

$Y(x)=c_1sinh\lambda_1x+c_2cosh\lambda_1x+c_3sin\lambda_2x+c_4cos\lambda_2x$

I've reverse worked out by substituting and rearranging the last equation to obtain the last before one. But not pretty clear with it. Any help on the step-by-step procedure and better understanding would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: \begin{align}
c_{1}e^{\lambda x}&=\frac{1}{2}c_{1}e^{\lambda x}+\frac{1}{2}c_{1}e^{\lambda x}+\frac{1}{2}c_{1}e^{-\lambda x}-\frac{1}{2}c_{1}e^{-\lambda x}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}c_{1}\left(e^{\lambda x}+e^{-\lambda x}\right)+\frac{1}{2}c_{1}\left(e^{\lambda x}-e^{-\lambda x} \right)\\
&=c_{1}\cosh(\lambda x)+c_{1} \sinh(\lambda x)
\end{align} and similarly for the other three. Note that this instantly tells you that $\sinh(- \lambda x) = - \sinh(\lambda x)$. Also note that the constants in your $Y(x)$ _are not the same_ in the cases where you have written it in exponentials and then sin\sinh etc.

Comment: @mattos: Thank you. Could you tell why this form is preferred? Any insights?

Comment: I don't think you can generalise and say one form is preferred over another. Some people might have a preference towards sin\sinh because it might be easier to read rather than exponentials, or maybe because the exponential form has a mixture of real and complex components while the sin\sinh form is entirely real. It just depends on who you are talking to I guess.

Comment: @mattos: Oh okay. Thank you again for your help.